# Nested select statements in impala sql

Tags: sql, impala

I have the following SQL query in impala

```
SELECT currentdate,close
FROM ( SELECT * FROM spyprice)
Where currentdate between '2015-01-16' and '2016-06-17';
```

And it is giving me the error:

```
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication

ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 15:
  WHERE currentdate BETWEEN '2015-01-16' and '2016-06-17'
^
 Encountered: WHERE
  Expected: AS, DEFAULT, IDENTIFIER

 CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

Anyone knows what's going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use an alias for the subquery.

Comment: I would speculate that a table alias is needed, but the documentation for Impala explicitly (soft of) says that one is not needed (SELECT currentdate,close
FROM ( SELECT * FROM spyprice)
Where currentdate between '2015-01-16' and '2016-06-17';).

Comment: I am sure the issue here is an alias of your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

@James Xiang The right syntax of the query statement is :

```
SELECT a.currentdate, a.close FROM 
( 
SELECT * FROM spyprice
) a
Where a.currentdate between '2015-01-16' and '2016-06-17';
```